# SMART data not available/readable on a modern computer

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have administration of a computer - Compaq CQ1-2025 - that has not been hardware modified in any way. According to specifications it has a 320 GB SATA hard disk in it. When I ran SpinRite disk utility on it it said it could not read the SMART data from the hard drive. I cannot imagine a drive modern enough to be SATA not having SMART data publishing. Am I wrong? I know SpinRite can read SMART data because it has done so on other machines. Is this a bug in it or a hardware issue?

Comment: Do you use on-board RAID?

Comment: No, this machine does not have hardware RAID capabilities.

Comment: SpinRite? Try [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be to try different software that can read the SMART data on a disk. Try, for example, the free [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) software. This monitors temperatures of your CPU, etc. as well, but it can look at SMART data.

Comment: This worked. SpinRite must just not be able to handle the newer drive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there are SATA drives without SMART. Most probably this is some kind of software issue with SpinRite. Try some other software, like [Argus Monitor](http://www.argotronic.com/en/) (works with many different chipsets).

Comment: This would sound right - I wouldn't trust SpinRite with anything essential, as it has a habit of messing up on newer drives...

Answer (score -1):

You can even try looking for smart data by booting through a bootable ubuntu pendrive and opening the preinstalled application "disks". Search for it in the dashboard.